# Изменение стиля блока с hover подсказкой JS

Tags: javascript, css, hover

При наведении всплывает подсказка с текстом,все отлично работает но необходимо, чтобы весь блок с картинкой позади затемнялся, при всплывании этой подсказки, как на скриншоте.

Реализовано с помощью JS, так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($(document).width() > 992) {
    $('.one').hover(function() {
        var color = $(this).css('background-color'),
        hint = $(this).find('.morehover');
        if (($(hint).text()).trim() == "") return 0;
        $(hint).css('border-top-color', color).clearQueue().delay(450).slideDown();
    }, function() {
        var hint = $(this).find('.morehover').first();
        $(hint).clearQueue().delay(250).slideUp();
    });
}});
```

Разметка элемента такая:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="img-logo-cat">
        <img alt="" src="/netcat_files/10/155/c03be3b7f90de4fc64548be018809953">
        <div class="link-not-link">
            test.ru
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image"><img alt="" src="/netcat_files/10/155/dc635fb6b1507887f611dfe89f090729"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="more">
        <div class="morehover" style="border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none;">
            Текст
            <div class="ssilka-podrob">
                <a class="ssilka-podrob-link" href="%E2%84%96">Подробнее <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div><span></span><a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">Перейти на сайт</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: скрин элемента]

Comment: Ваш HTML невалидный. И было бы не лишним прикрепить CSS код тоже. Проблему лучше решить на JS или на чистом CSS и HTML?

Comment: Привел в порядок html, а нужно решить - совершенно не важно как, главное чтоб заработало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На `html` + `css`. Был создан новый `div` с `z-index` больше, чем у `img`. При наведении он становиться менее непрозрачным.

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one>img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index:1;
}

.one>.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background:black;
  z-index:2;
}

.one:hover>.backdrop {
  opacity: .5;
}

.more {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size:12px;
  z-index:3;
}

.one:hover>.more {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.more>* {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ssilka-podrob {
  text-align: right;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <img alt="" src="https://d7h8sdtmi2h3e.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1024x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/E/D/EDBGB601.jpg">
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
  <div class="more">
    <div class="morehover">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, verear nominati eu sed. Qui doming regione urbanitas id, accusam oporteat similique cu nam. Cu velit graeci concludaturque sed, eu fierent appetere fabellas est.
      <div class="ssilka-podrob">
        <a class="ssilka-podrob-link" href="%E2%84%96">Подробнее ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">Перейти на сайт</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!